# Return TRUE if two conditions are met but one of them has two options

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Google sheets issue. I want a formula that will return TRUE or FALSE if two conditions are met. However for one of the conditions there are two possibilities.

**IF** A2="Pizza **OR** Banana" **AND** B2="Food" then return TRUE

How can I go about it? For now I did the following but I am missing one option (banana):

```
=IF(AND($A2="Pizza"),$B2="Food")
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a formula like

`=IF(AND(OR(A2="Pizza", A2="Banana"), B2="Food"), TRUE, FALSE)`

Edit:
As pointed out by MattKing, you don't need the `IF` here at all since `AND` will give you `TRUE`/`FALSE`, you can just use:

`=AND(OR(A2="Pizza", A2="Banana"), B2="Food")`

Comment: don't need the IF() at all right?
=AND(OR(A2="Pizza",A2="Banana"),B2="Food")

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, it worked. What if I wanted it to not be case sensitive and to work with Food-FOOD-food and other variants?

Comment: @coffee709 for case insensitivity you can use the `LOWER` function: `=AND(OR(LOWER(A2)="pizza", LOWER(A2)="banana"), LOWER(B2)="food")`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=((A2="Pizza")+(A2="Banana"))*(B2="Food")
```

Answer (score 0):

> What if I wanted it to not be case sensitive and to work with Food-FOOD-food and other variants?

```
=AND(REGEXMATCH($A$2,"(?i)^pizza$|^banana$"),REGEXMATCH($B$2,"(?i)food"))
```

Use REGEXMATCH instead gives you more control on the conditions.
In this example,

the first REGEXMATCH will do non-case-sensitive check on A2 to see if it is a word started with 'p' end with 'a' spell as 'pizza' or started with 'b' end with 'a' spell as 'banana' (if anything is added before or after 'pizza' and 'banana', such as 'ppizzaa', it returns false),

the second REGEXMATCH do non-case-sensitive check on B2 to see if it is any variants which includes 'food' (even something like 'xFooDy' will return true).